# denoising image with opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying denoising the color image using OpenCV with function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored this for large image it is too much time to denoise any alternative algorithm to remove noise of image using OpenCV in c++ with examples

Comment: What time did you measure and what is your expectation? There are quite a few algorithms implemented in `opencv`, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html). All too slow for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Nvidia's Optix SDK denoiser, it gave me a denoised image in about  less than 1 sec, unless you want something real time, you can try that. They say its AI based and also it uses your GPU with Cuda library so it is safe to say that to quite fast and almost realtime denoising.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example of using Gaussian and median blurs to denoise image. You can use this code to test denoising algs with your image and choose the best in time/quality parameters. Time, spending to compute denoised image is output to console in seconds.

My average times are:
GaussianBlur 0.0747621
medianBlur 0.0100638
NlMeans 1.07519

Use keys '1', '2', '3', '4' to watch original, NlMeans, median or Gaussian resilt respectively. 'q' to end programm. I found it convenient to compare denoising results by simply switching images, while maintaining pixel-by-pixel correspondence.
You can change `int k_sz` and `double gauss_sigma` values to change the degree of blur.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <string>    

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;    

int main()
{

  Mat frame;
  frame = imread("E:\\images\\pair_noised.jpg");

  while (1)
  {
    Mat gaus;
    Mat median;
    Mat NlMeans;

    int k_sz = 5;
    double gauss_sigma = 1.6;
    try {
      TickMeter tm;
      tm.start();
      GaussianBlur(frame, gaus, Size(k_sz, k_sz), gauss_sigma);
      tm.stop();
      cout << "GaussianBlur " <<tm.getTimeSec() << endl;
      tm.reset();

      tm.start();
      medianBlur(frame, median, k_sz);
      tm.stop();
      cout << "medianBlur " << tm.getTimeSec() << endl;
      tm.reset();

      tm.start();
      fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(frame, NlMeans);
      tm.stop();
      cout << "NlMeans " << tm.getTimeSec() << endl;
      tm.reset();
    }
    catch(Exception& Ex)
    {
      cout << Ex.what() << endl;
    }

    string win_nm = "output";
    namedWindow(win_nm);

    char key = waitKey();

    switch (key)
    {
    case '4':
      imshow(win_nm, gaus);
      break;
    case '3':
      imshow(win_nm, median);
      break;
    case '2':
      imshow(win_nm, NlMeans);
      break;
    case '1':
      imshow(win_nm, frame);
      break;

    case 'q':
      return 0;

    default:
      imshow(win_nm, frame);
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```